# How to access specific value in php and json

Tags: php, json

I'm using a token:

```
$url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?api_token=3bd884bb0078f836a56f1464097fb71eac9d50ce";
```

and here's the json text(not everything);

```
    {
     "success":true,
     "data":[{
            "id":1,
            "creator_user_id":{
                        "id":1682756,
                        "name":"Kamilah",
                        "email":"kamilah@fractal.ae",
                        "has_pic":false,
                        "pic_hash":null,
                        "active_flag":true, 
                        "value":1682756},
                        "title":"FFS Organization deal"
            }]
    }
```

I wanted to display "title" and I always get an error

> Notice: Undefined index: creator_user_id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pipedrive\getjson.php on line 8

Here's my code so far:

```
$url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?api_token=3bd884bb0078f836a56f1464097fb71eac9d50ce";

$response = file_get_contents($url);
$object = json_decode($response, true);

echo $object['data']['creator_user_id']['title'];
```

I'm new to json so I'm just practicing and trying to figure out how to echo a specific value in php. Would be appreciated if you can explain exactly how it works when you echo from json to php.

Thank you! :)

Comment: `$object['data'][0]['creator_user_id']['title']`

Comment: it looks like data is a json array(as indicated by the [ ] in the json string), so you should use [0] between data and creator_user_id

Comment: you have two ids in this array not 1

Comment: this will work for you `foreach ($object['data'] as $key => $value) {
 //print_r($value);
 echo $value['title']."<br/>";
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to debug the array after using `json_decode()`.

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?api_token=3bd884bb0078f836a56f1464097fb71eac9d50ce";

$response = file_get_contents($url);
$object = json_decode($response, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($object); // this will print all data into array format.
?>
```

As per this array, you do not have `title` index inside the `creator_user_id` array. `title` is a separate index.

Also note that, `$object['data']` containing two indexes not one. you can get `title` as:

```
<?php
foreach ($object['data'] as $key => $value) {
    //print_r($value); // this will print the values inside the data array.
    echo $value['title']."<br/>"; // this will print all title inside your array.
}
?>
```

**Result:**

```
FFS Organization deal
Google deal
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I didn't notice that the title was not inside creator_user_id. Helped a lot :D